# My Drawer Layout is not active with relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm not able to either open fragment in drawer or my layout listeners doesn't work. I need an example of xml containing drawerlayout and some other layout. Below is my code of in xml.

```
  <RelativeLayout 
  ....some initialisation
```

Relative layout holding toolbar

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="64dp"
                android:background="#0D4050" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/actionbar_imageview"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:maxHeight="50dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/symbol" />
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Relative layout holding my custom views

```
<RelativeLayout 
                android:id="@+id/rl1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" 
                >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="300dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/snt"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/cts"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
                android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar" 
                >
```

Frame layout serves as my fragment holder

```
                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/home_fragment_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <!-- The navigation drawer -->
```

Listview to display drawer

```
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried inserting rl1 in  drawerlayout also added it as a topmost layer but either drawerlayout doesnt load fragments or I'm not able to call the onclick listeners on rl1.
re
Also, I tried hiding and showing the layouts dynamically but same result. :(
My expectaion is working sample of drawerlaout with some custom view.